# Running cron job inside container with python code and postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, cron

I am new into docker, and I have created a container with python + postgres, which runs a python script that collects some data and writes it down on the SQL database. Now, I need to set this job to run each day. And then the nightmare started. I did not manage to create a separate container for this job, so I tried to  create a file and copy it into the container via DockerFile (see this one down). I did not manage to run cron as entry-point for the container because then my database was not mounted. So, I create the container, access it, give full permissions to /var/www/html, and create the database table. And then I run cron. No erro, but nothing happens, no log is written on /var/log/cron.log. Here my files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y install cron nano
RUN apt-get -y install postgresql-server-dev-10 gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip3 install psycopg2 \
    bs4 \
    requests \
    pytz
    
COPY temp-alerts-cron /etc/cron.d/temp-alerts-cron
RUN chmod 0777 /etc/cron.d/temp-alerts-cron
RUN chmod gu+rw /var/run/
RUN chmod gu+s /usr/sbin/cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN chmod 0777 /var/log/cron.log
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/temp-alerts-cron

USER postgres

EXPOSE 5432

VOLUME ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]
```

The temp-alers-cron:

```
20 13 * * * root /var/www/html/run.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job
```

And the called script:

```
echo 'inside thingy'  >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
python3 /var/www/html/nuria_main.py
```

In case it is needed, here the docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  postgres: 
    container_name: 'temp-postgres'
    build: # build the image from Dockerfile
      context: ${PWD}   
    volumes: # bind mount volume for Postgres data
     - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     - ./python-app:/var/www/html
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USR=xxadmin
     - POSTGRES_DB=tempdb
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret        
    expose:
     - "5432"   
    networks:
      kong:
networks:
  kong:
    external:
      name: kong_net
volumes:
  pg-data:
```

Hope somebody knows what I am doing wrong. I do not get any log or error, so i am lost.
Thanks!

Comment: A container only runs one process; what is the single process this container will run?  You might build a separate image `FROM python`, without including a PostgreSQL server in that image, to contain the program you want to run and the cron daemon to launch it.

Comment: Yes, David is right. The point of a docker container is to have one "thing" running per container. If you want a fuller system with cron and other services available you want a system container like [lxc / lxd](https://linuxcontainers.org/). Or something like "docker compose" that handles several containers together.

Comment: Hi! thanks. I tried it, but I am not being able to do it because I do not understand how docker works :( But I managed to make it work the dirty way. After installing syslog in my container, I realized that the time in the server was not the same as in my machine. So, actually, I was asking sth to run in two minutes, but in the server was 1 hour and two minutes. There was just one error: I needed to rmeove "root" from the temp-alers-cron file.